# ClassCastException in Java

Tags: java, classcastexception

I'm getting a ClassCastException in the below code, which doesn't make much sense to me, as `targetObject` is a Comparable and `current` is a ToBeFound. Where are the Integer and String coming from?

```
ToBeFound origin = new ToBeFound();
public ToBeFound findWrapper(Comparable targetObject)
{
    return find(origin, targetObject);
}

private ToBeFound find(ToBeFound current, Comparable targetObject)
{
    if (current == null)
        {
        return null;
        }

    System.out.println(targetObject.compareTo(current.getValue()));
     // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
     // java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

    return new ToBeFound();
}

//body of main() that calls the methods
master.find( (Comparable) scanner.next()); 
   // Scanner is a java.util.Scanner scanning System.in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `compareTo` javadoc states:

> ClassCastException - if the specified object's type prevents it from being compared to this object.

It seems that your `target` is of a `String` type which is `Comparable<String>` and `current.getValue()` returns an object of `Integer` type.

You can try to do `String.valueOf(current.getValue)` if it works ok then I'm right. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private ToBeFound find(TreeNode current, Comparable targetObject)
```

Looks like `current` is a `TreeNode`...

Comment: Oh, no, sorry. That was part of the anonymoization of the code that I hadn't caught.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(target.compareTo(current.getValue()));
```

Return type of `compareTo` is int, so you can convert your primitive int to String using

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(target.compareTo(current.getValue())));
```

What is the type of target? Seems like you are comparing String against Integer.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample code is reflects what you are actually running then:

```
System.out.println(target.compareTo(current.getValue()));
```

1. Your code does not show the declaration for `target`, but the exception message implies that it *must* be `String`.  (You show use the declaration for `targetObject` ... but that's not what the code is actually using!!)
2. Your code doesn't show the declaration for the `ToBeFound.getValue()` method ... but the exception message implies that it *must* be `Integer`.
3. The `String.compareTo(Object)` throws a CCE if the parameter object is not a String.